# Two javascript functions, the second one waits for the first to retrieve a value using getScript, from an external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Maybe you can help with an elegant way to link two functions together.

1. The first one retrieves a value using 'getScript' from an external url.
2. The second one, waits for the first func. to get that value and does
   something with it.

Here is what I have tried, everything should work **apart from the waiting part** (them most imp) :)

I have commented the code for better understanding:

```
/**
 * Test Class.
 */
 var Test = function() {

    var cookieEmail;

    this.init = function() {

        var script = 'http://www.script.com';

        jQuery.getScript(script, function(){
            cookieEmail = typeof (functionOnScriptCom) == 'undefined' ? '' : functionOnScriptCom('V_ElqEmailAddress');
        }
    }

    this.init2 = function(){
        // I want to do something with the variable "cookieEmail", after it has been retrieved using getScript.
        cookieEmail = cookieEmail.toLowerCase();
    }

 }

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var test = new Test();

    test.init();
    // I need a way to wait for -- test.init -- getScript function to retrieve the ---cookieEmail--- value.
    // When cookieEmail's value has been retrieved, I want to be able to call:

    test.init2();

 });
```

Comment: That is what callbacks are for. Pass in a reference to the function, execute it when the first is done.

Comment: I sense that this would be a great use for `promise` objects. See [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass a callback to the `init` function that will be executed after the `getScript` executes successfully.  Something like this:

```
var Test = function() {

    var cookieEmail;

    this.init = function( callback ) {

        var script = 'http://www.script.com';

        jQuery.getScript(script, function(){
            cookieEmail = typeof (functionOnScriptCom) == 'undefined' ? '' : functionOnScriptCom('V_ElqEmailAddress');
            callback();
        }
    }

    this.init2 = function(){
        // I want to do something with the variable "cookieEmail", after it has been retrieved using getScript.
        cookieEmail = cookieEmail.toLowerCase();
    }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var test = new Test();

    test.init( function() { test.init2(); });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not going to wait since `getScript` is an async call, so you should modify `init()` to accept a callback function, then run `init2` in that callback:

```
this.init = function(callback) {
    var cookieEmail;
    var script = 'http://www.script.com';

    jQuery.getScript(script, function(){
        cookieEmail = typeof (functionOnScriptCom) == 'undefined' ? '' : functionOnScriptCom('V_ElqEmailAddress');
        callback(cookieEmail);
    }
}

//Modify init2 to accept a param
this.init2 = function(cookieEmail){
```

Now you can do:

```
test.init(function(data) {
    init2(data);
}
```

Comment: @Steve -- Thanks for seeing that, this would've put OP back in the same spot he was lol.

Answer (score 0):

[The response from AJAX (including `getScript` JSONP) is always *asynchronous*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call). So use the promise pattern:

```
var test = {
    init: function() {
        var script = 'http://www.script.com';
        return jQuery.getScript(script).then(function(){
            return typeof (functionOnScriptCom) == 'undefined' ? '' : functionOnScriptCom('V_ElqEmailAddress');
        });
    },
    init2: function(promise){
        return promise.then(function(cookieEmail) {
            // do something with `cookieEmail` when it has arrived
            return cookieEmail.toLowerCase();
        });
    }
};

test.init2(test.init());
```